# remove string in list in awt java

Tags: java, list

In my application i should remove a string from list when running on the thread,But i got the exception 
like,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: item gh not found in list
    at java.awt.List.remove(Unknown Source)
    at org.sample.ChatClient$updateClient$1.run(ChatClient.java:200)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
final Map<String, String> liHashMap=list;
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : liHashMap.entrySet()) {
            String client_Name=entry.getKey();
            if(!checkList.containsKey(client_Name)) {
                lst.add(client_Name + "\n");
                checkList.put(client_Name, ipAddress);
            }
        }
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : checkList.entrySet()) {
            String client_Name=entry.getKey();
            if(!liHashMap.containsKey(client_Name)){
                lst.remove(client_Name);//Remove string from list
                checkList.remove(client_Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: item gh not found in list` Have you checked in your code if that item exists? I think that error it's pretty clear. Also, you should need to upload where and how you introduce `Strings` to your lists (code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here. Change this:

```
if(!liHashMap.containsKey(client_Name)){
                lst.remove(client_Name);//Remove string from list
                checkList.remove(client_Name);
        }
```

To this:

```
if(liHashMap.containsKey(client_Name)){
                lst.remove(client_Name);//Remove string from list
                checkList.remove(client_Name);
        }
```

I am assuming your hash map is a backing store of items to be removed from for your list. Right? Therefore, you should only remove the key if it is in the hash map and thus in the list.

If that is not the way it works, then you need to maintain a list of items that should be removed, and that you have verified that are, in fact, in the list, and then remove them. Like this:

```
if(toBeRemovedMap.containsKey(client_Name)){
                lst.remove(client_Name);//Remove string from list
                checkList.remove(client_Name);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

An `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown if the passed value doesn't exist in the `java.awt.List`.

If you use `java.util.List`, that would return `true` if the passed value exists else `false`.